# Sending a voice message from an OGG file using the InsanusMokrassar/TelegramBotAPI

Tags: kotlin, telegram, ktgbotapi

I am using the InsanusMokrassar/TelegramBotAPI (AKA @ktgbotapi) to make a simple bot that sends random messages to a group of friends. I was wondering, how can I send a voice message starting from an .ogg file I already have that sound inside my package. Now I am trying to use `bot.sendVoice()` but it asks for a `VoiceFile` that I don't know how to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use [sendVoice](https://tgbotapi.inmo.dev/tgbotapi.api/dev.inmo.tgbotapi.extensions.api.send.media/send-voice.html) with [InputFile](https://tgbotapi.inmo.dev/tgbotapi.core/dev.inmo.tgbotapi.requests.abstracts/-multipart-file/index.html) created from `MPPFile` (common `File` on JVM) with [asMultipartFile](https://tgbotapi.inmo.dev/tgbotapi.core/dev.inmo.tgbotapi.requests.abstracts/as-multipart-file.html) extension